# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-loader

I've got an error while building a project:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
```

[image]

My development environment is as follows:

Node: 8.0.0
npm: 5.0.0

devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.7"
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`babel-loader@8.x`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#install) uses Babel 7.x, which is `@babel/core@^7.0.0`, and more importantly in your case `@babel/preset-env@7` replaces `babel-preset-env@^1.7.0`.

You'll need to make sure to do

```
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and update your Babel config to use `@babel/preset-env` instead of `babel-preset-env` with something like

```
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

Note: For others coming across this, the issue may also be that you're using plugins/preset from Babel 6 on Babel 7. This may be hard to notice if you're using a third-party Babel preset since the versions of the presets may not match the version of Babel itself.

Comment: I encountered this issue, I had done the above but found removing `airbnb` from my presets in `.babelrc` remedied the issue (obviously not compatible with v7).

Comment: I had the settings in `gulpfile.js` and so I didn't notice them for a long time.

Answer (score 8):

The error can show with this message too:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module './src/data'
```

I'm fixed it, with:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
```

**or using:** `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env`

Obs.: I didn't need to create a **.babelrc** file, to configure preset.